# InvalidS3ObjectException when calling the AnalyzeDocument operation:

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

InvalidS3ObjectException when calling the AnalyzeDocument operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions."
I keep getting this error. Over. And. Over. This program worked with my test cases of what I'm bringing in, the json with a  {"body":"imagename.jpg"}. But the very moment I try to utilize the actual code my JS brings in, I get this error. The thing that confuses me is that I've checked the regions and they are fine. I went into my account and created users with full access to all AWS and S3 features, and utilized those logins, I've used my root account, everything. All I'm trying to do is access an image from my s3 bucket. Why won't it work? Below is my code. It works if I utilize the test case I provided above, but the moment I try and use the website it's connected to, it doesn't work.

```
def main(event, context):
    key_map, value_map, block_map = get_kv_map(event)   #Take map variables in to get the key and value map we need.
```

It goes to this function...

```
def get_kv_map(event): 
    filePath = event
    fileExt = filePath.get('body')
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-1')

    bucket = s3.Bucket('react-images-ex')
    obj = bucket.Object(bucket)

    client = boto3.client('textract') #We utilize boto3's textract lib 
    response = client.analyze_document(Document={'S3Object': {'Bucket': 'react-images-ex', 'Name': fileExt}}, FeatureTypes=['FORMS'])
# Get the text blocks
    blocks=response['Blocks']     #We make a blocks variable that will be the blocks we find in the document
# get key and value maps
    key_map = {}
    value_map = {}
    block_map = {}
    for block in blocks:        #Traverse the blocks found in the document
        block_id = block['Id']          #Set variable for blockId to the Id's found on that block location
        block_map[block_id] = block                 #Make the block map at that ID be the block variable
        if block['BlockType'] == "KEY_VALUE_SET":       #if we see that the type of block we're on is a key and value set pair, we check if it's a key or not. If it's not a key, we know it's a value. We send it to the respective map. 
            if 'KEY' in block['EntityTypes']:
                key_map[block_id] = block
            else:
                value_map[block_id] = block
    return key_map, value_map, block_map                    #Return the maps we need after they're filled.
```

I have been told before this code is fine, and it should work. So why exactly is it that I get this error?

Comment: Have you inspected CoudWatch logs for any error messages?

Comment: Yes. It seems like it i something to do with the format of the jpg. When I bring in the JSON as event and return it, the jpg is formatted as such "\"147255.jpg\" rather than "147255.jpg" for some reason.

Comment: Can you try `fileExt = json.loads(filePath.get('body'))` to parse the string json into json object. May require changing subsequent parts accordingly.

Comment: So it works but now I get a gateway 502 error... 
Is it due to using the proxyurl? Does that make amazon block my requests? I have  const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"; set prior to the URL

Comment: Not sure about the proxy, but if you don't mind I can make answer about the json issue, for future reference. For the proxy, many new question would be a good idea with relevant details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue with `body` was that it was json string, not actual json object.

The solution was to parse the string into json:

```
fileExt = json.loads(filePath.get('body'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `awscli` to see if you can access the image in s3:

```
aws s3 ls s3://react-images-ex/<some-fileExt>
```

Either you are parsing the fileExt wrongly, or you don't have S3 permission to access the file. The awscli command will help to verify this.

Comment: So, when I enter tha tin the console, it does show the file extension fine. BUT I just checked an example of returning the json of my "event" and see that it provides "\"147255.jpg\"" if I change the format to be "147255.jpg" it works fine. Why is it formatted this way?

Comment: @bake : That depends on how your code is parsing `event`. Just try adding `event = event.strip("\"")` inside your function to remove any surrounding quote (if any)